# Togle to edit Mysql data from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I have a table in my php where I show data from my 'users' table of mysql. In the table I added an edit button so that, if you click on the button, a form is shown below the table where you can edit some fields of the table's content, I have also added a delete button next to it to delete the row of the table you want, but that button works correctly.

The problem I have is with the edit button, which, when pressed, it doesn’t show me the form that I added below the table, but it takes me to the page 'registerTeacher.php?edit = 3' for example. Pressing the 'Edit' button, it should show the form to be able to edit but it doesn’t do anything, nor does it show me any errors. Can someone help me find where the problem is? Thank you.

This is my ‘indexAdmin.php’ code:

```
<?php
include('server.php');
include('Security.php');
include('Conexion.php');
include('registerTeacher.php');
?>

<?php
$style = "style='display:none;'";
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;

    $record = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");

    if (@count($record) == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
        $username = $n['username']; 
        $email  = $n['email']; 
        $style = "style='display:block;'";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleIndexAdmin.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<!-- notification message -->
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
    <div class="error success" >
        <h3>
            <?php
            echo $_SESSION['success'];
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
            ?>
        </h3>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- logged in user information -->
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>


    <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <a class="tablink" onclick="openPage('professorsRegistered', this, 'lightblue')" id="defaultOpen">Profesores</a>
    </div>

    <!----------- PROFESSROS REGISTERED TABLE ----------->

    <div id="professorsRegistered" class="tabcontent"></br><br>

        <table class="professorsRegistered">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3"><h2>PROFESSORS REGISTERED</h2></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th> Edit </th>
                <th> Delete </th>
            </tr>

        <?php
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE rol='profesor'"; 
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows==0){
            echo 'No professors';
        }else{
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>
                          <td>".$row["username"]."</td>
                          <td><a href='registerTeacher.php?edit=".$row["id"]."' class='edit_btn' ><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' style='cursor:pointer;'></i></a></td>

                          <td><a class='eliminate' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Confirm to delete');\" href=\"deleteTeacher.php?id=".$row['id']."\">X</a></td>
                          </tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        </table><br><br>

        <!------- FORM TO EDIT REGISTERED TEACHERS ---------->
        <form method="post" action="registerTeacher.php" <?php echo $style;?>>
            <!----- newly added field--->
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>USER</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>EMAIL</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <!--------BUTTON----->
                <?php if ($update == true): ?>
                    <button class="btn_update" type="submit" name="update">EDIT</button>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<?php endif ?>

<script>
    function getUrlVars(){
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value){
            vars[key] =value;
        });
        return vars;
    }

    function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    p = getUrlVars()["page"];
    //alert(p);
    if (p==undefined){
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    }else{
        openPage(p, this, 'lightblue');
    }

</script>

</body>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
    <div class="msg">
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
</html>
```

This is my ‘registerTeacher.php’ file:

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php');

$username = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();
$id = 0;
$update = false;

// UPDATE
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET username='$username', email='$email' WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User edited!";
    header("Location: indexAdmin.php?page=professors");
}
?>
```

Comment: @Swati I have an example where I edited also with href and it did not redirected me to another page, everything worked correctly. This is what I put: '<a href="index_test.php?edit=<?php echo $ row['id']; ?> "class =" edit_btn "> <i class =" fa fa-pencil-square- or "style =" cursor: pointer; "> </ i> </a>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<a href=..>` is used to redirect to some page in your case ,it is redirecting to `registerTeacher.php`page as you have specify  in your `href` attribute.Instead you can do like below :

When below `<a href..>` is clicked you can put form on `registerTeacher.php` like below :

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $update = true;

        $record = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");

        if (@count($record) == 1 ) {
            $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
            $username = $n['username']; 
            $email  = $n['email']; 
            $style = "style='display:block;'";
        }
    }
?>

     <!------- FORM TO EDIT REGISTERED TEACHERS ---------->
        <form method="post" action="abcpage.php" <?php echo $style;?>>
            <!----- newly added field--->
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>USER</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>EMAIL</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <!--------BUTTON----->
                <?php if ($update == true): ?>
                    <button class="btn_update" type="submit" name="update">EDIT</button>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Then you can passed this details to your `action="abcpage.php"`.and write like below in that page i.e :

```
// UPDATE
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET username='$username', email='$email' WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User edited!";
    header("Location: indexAdmin.php?page=professors");
}
?>
```

Hope this helps !

***Note*** : Also try using [**prepared statement**](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) it is safe an secure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @swati, I tried but still doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is something from here but with the form hidden: https://codewithawa.com/posts/php-crud-create,-edit,-update-and-delete-posts-with-mysql-database

Comment: Okay here `registerTeacher.php?edit=".$row["id"]."` replace this with `indexAdmin.php?edit=".$row["id"]."` and see once in your code

Comment: Wow it worked! It was only that okay... Thank you very much! You helped me a lot :D

Comment: glad i helped .. happy coding :)